# Java movement issus in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, keylistener

I made a program where there is a green square in the JFrame and you press the key "A" and "D" to move left and right (A=left, D=right). But when i run the program the square won't move when the A/D keys are pressed. I tried to check my code for error but i couldn't find any. If you can tell me where my code is wrong then that would be awesome!!

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

    public class four extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
    static int x=0, y=0;  
    static int x1=0, y1=0;  
    static int width=500,height=600;        
    static JFrame f;  
    boolean left, right;  
    boolean playGame = true;

public void paintComponent (Graphics g){        
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(x,100,700,100);
    g.drawRect(x,200,700,100);
    g.drawRect(x,300,700,100);
    g.drawRect(x,400,700,100);
    g.drawRect(x,500,700,100);
    g.drawRect(x,600,700,100);
    g.drawRect(x,700,700,100);
    g.drawRect(100,100,100,700);
    g.drawRect(200,100,0,700);
    g.drawRect(300,100,0,700);
    g.drawRect(400,100,0,700);
    g.drawRect(500,100,0,700);
    g.drawRect(600,100,0,700);
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(x1, y1, 100, 100);
}
public static void main(String[] args){  
    four q=new four();
    JFrame f=new JFrame("Connect 4");
    q.init(); 
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    f.add(q);
    f.setSize(700,820);
    f.setVisible(true);
} 
public void init (){
    this.addKeyListener(this);  
    setFocusable(true);  

}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (left==true)             
    {
        x1=x1-100;
    }
    if (right==true)             
    {
        x1=x1+100;
    }
    f.repaint();
    System.out.println(x1);
    }

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){  
        left=true;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D){  
        left=true;
    }
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){  
        left=false;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D){  
        right=false;
    }
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Call `super.paintComponent` before performing any custom painting
2. Use the key bindings API over `KeyListener`, it solves the focus related issues that `KeyListener` suffers from. See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details
3. Initialise the UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details
4. What's calling the `actionPerformed` method? I think you want to take a closer look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)